# Outlook/Exchange rule does not move every email it should match

Tags: exchange-2013

I have created a rule in Outlook to move all emails with `backup@example.com` in the `From:` field to a specific folder.

However, the rule apparently does not match every email it *should* match, as only *some* emails are moved.

These are the headers of a mail that *is* correctly moved:

```
Received: from desktop.example.com (10.0.1.106) by
 exchange.example.com (10.0.0.13) with Microsoft SMTP Server id
 14.3.301.0; Tue, 16 Aug 2016 13:48:37 +0200
Date: Tue, 16 Aug 2016 13:48:39 +0200
From: <backup@example.com>
To: <it@example.com>
Message-ID: <1750881267.1.1471348119454.JavaMail.desktop$@desktop>
Subject: Arcserve Unified Data Protection Alert-Sichern
 Jobstatus:Fertiggestellt(desktop)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_Part_0_1224834770.1471348119242"
Return-Path: backup@example.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: exchange.example.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Anonymous
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Mailbox: Sophos;-1278081278;0;PM
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: DR, OOF, AutoReply
```

Here are the headers for one that *isn't* moved:

```
Received: from server (10.0.1.81) by exchange.example.com
 (10.0.0.13) with Microsoft SMTP Server id 14.3.301.0; Wed, 17 Aug 2016
 03:04:59 +0200
Date: Wed, 17 Aug 2016 03:04:59 +0200
From: <backup@example.com>
To: <it@example.com>
Message-ID: <2061725264.69.1471395899278.JavaMail.server$@server>
Subject: Arcserve Unified Data Protection Alert-Dateisystemkatalog
 Jobstatus:Fertiggestellt(server)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_Part_68_1541009446.1471395899262"
Return-Path: backup@example.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: exchange.example.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 10
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Mailbox: Sophos;-1278063614;0;PM
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: DR, OOF, AutoReply
```

To me, this looks pretty much identical. Especially in the regard that the `From` field matches my rule exactly.

One key difference in Outlook though is that the emails that *aren't* moved also appear differently in the inbox. For the mails that *are* moved, Outlook shows the sender address (`backup@example.com`) in the first column of the overview, for those that *aren't* moved, it shows the name of the mailbox owner `IT Department`.

Comment: "X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs" is the only difference I can see. I wonder if that affects the mailbox owner somehow.

Comment: @DavidPostill What I find confusing is, there is an Exchange Receive Connector configured to accept anonymous transmissions from `server`. I assume that's why the `AuthAs` is `Internal`. Reading this now, I don't even understand why `desktop` is allowed to send messages (unless I'm misreading the headers). However, this really doesn't make it less confusing. Because, if anything, I would disable access for `desktop`, leaving me with *no* mails correctly moved.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so familiar with this stuff. My first comment was just an observation ...

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this:

> with backup@example.com in the To: field

but in the headers backup@example.com is in the from field...
Maybe a simple mistake of referring the wrong field?

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. I meant the `From` field. Will update the question.